# html5 websockets OR flash sockets activated on load?

Tags: php, python, sockets

I want to ask you guys, how to make my php (or python) socket server to start when a client make request to a specific file and to stop, when client stops. Also, is there a way to make a php or python socket server not to open any ports (maybe to use port 80, which I think is possible, thanks to the request above). I'm using a public hosting which doesn't allow me to open ports or to use terminal commands.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, sorry, you can't do WebSockets (at least not properly to my knowledge) without opening ports. You might be able to fake it with PHP, but the timeout would defeat it.

I would recommend Comet AJAX/long-polling instead.